# Html css overlapping divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage where I have some divs which are tiles on the page.
These all float to the left and only so many tiles are displayed depending on the permissions of the user logging onto the page.

The tiles, when hovered over, then display suboptions which a user can click and navigate too.

There is one tile one the page that I wish to expand, which I have done, changed the css class of this tile when it is hovered over using Javascript.

My problem is that I wish for this new larger tile to overlap the other smaller tiles on the page. The only thing I can get it to do at the moment is to display under the other tiles on the page and not to overlap them.

Below is my code:

```
<center>
  <asp:Table id="Table2" height="1000" align="center" table-layout="auto" style="margin-top: 25px;" max-width="1000" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow>
      <asp:TableCell width="1000">
        <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483569') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483560') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483497')">
          <div class="smalltile" align="center" id="receipting" style="padding-right: 10px;" onmouseover="receiptingHover();" onmouseout="receiptingHoverOut();">
            <br/>
            <label id="receiptlabel" style="position: relative; top: 37px;" class="menuLabelFont">Receipting</label>
            <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483569')">
              <a href="javascript:Submit('../Payments/CashIntranetPayments.aspx','../Common/','');" title="Take customer present and customer not present payments using all payment types" style="cursor: pointer;" class="menuLabelInitiallyHidden" id="browserreceiptinglabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">Receipting</a>
            <br/>
            <br/>
              </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483560')">
              <a href="javascript:Submit('javascript:Submit('../Sales/LaunchIntranet.aspx','../Common/','');" title="Display your sale forms in Intranet (not internet) mode and pay using the Card Payments module" style="cursor: pointer;" class="menuLabelInitiallyHidden" id="intraneteformslabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">Intranet eForms</a>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483497')">
              <a href="javascript:Submit('../Explorer/ViewTable.aspx?tablepath=CCPProfiles.xml','../Common/','');" title="CCPPlan Configuration" style="cursor: pointer;" class="menuLabelInitiallyHidden" id="ccpplans" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">CCP Instalment Plans</a>
            </xsl:if>
          </div>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483568')">
          <a href="javascript:Submit('../Reporting/SelectReport.aspx','../Common/','');" title="PARIS Reports Library">
            <div class="smalltile" align="center" id="reporting" style="cursor: pointer; padding-top: 57px; padding-right: 10px;" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">
            <span id="reportinglabel" class="menuLabelFont">Reporting</span>
            </div>
          </a>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483565') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483567') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483565') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483567')">
          <div class="smalltile" align="center" id="sundryincomereturns" style="padding-right: 10px;" onmouseover="sundryIncomeHover();" onmouseout="sundryIncomeHoverOut();">
            <br/>
            <label id="sundrydebtorslabel" style="position: relative; top: 37px;" class="menuLabelFont">Sundry Income Returns</label>
            <!--<xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483565')">
              <a href="javascript:Submit('../PARISMVC/Reconciliation/Reconciliation/index','../Common/','');" title="Manage Reconciliation of Sundry Income Returns" style="cursor: pointer;" class="menuLabelInitiallyHidden" id="reconciliationlabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">Reconciliation</a>
            <br/>
            <br/>
              </xsl:if>-->
            <!--<xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483567')">
              <a href="javascript:Submit('../PARISMVC/Returns/Home/Index','../Common/','');" title="Manage Sundry Income Returns" style="cursor: pointer;" class="menuLabelInitiallyHidden" id="sundryincomelabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">Returns</a>
            <br/>
            <br/>
              </xsl:if>-->
            <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483565')">
              <a href="javascript:Submit('../PARISMVC/Reconciliation/Reconciliation/index','../Common/','');" title="Manage Reconciliation of Online Returns" style="cursor: pointer;" class="menuLabelInitiallyHidden" id="reconversionone" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">Reconciliation</a>
            <br/>
            <br/>
              </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483567')">
              <a href="javascript:Submit('../PARISMVC/Returns/Home/Index','../Common/','');" title="Manage Online Returns" style="cursor: pointer;" class="menuLabelInitiallyHidden" id="returnsversionone" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">Returns</a>
            </xsl:if>
          </div>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483566')">
          <div class="smalltile" align="center" id="transactions" style="padding-right: 10px;" onmouseover="transactionsHover();" onmouseout="transactionsHoverOut();">
            <br/>
              <label id="transactionslabel" style="position: relative; top: 37px;" class="menuLabelFont">Transactions</label>
            <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483566')">
              <a href="javascript:Submit('../Explorer/SelectTable.aspx?tablemenufile=transactions%20table%20menu.xml','../Common/','');" title="Examine the receipting transactions" style="cursor: pointer;" class="menuLabelInitiallyHidden" id="viewtransactiondatalabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">View Transactions</a>
            <br/>
            <br/>
              <a href="javascript:Submit('../Explorer/SelectTable.aspx?tablemenufile=saleforms.xml&amp;foldername=Sales/Transactions','../Common/','');" title="View sale form transactions by type of sale form" style="cursor: pointer;" class="menuLabelInitiallyHidden" id="vieweformtransactiondatalabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">View eForm Transactions</a>
            </xsl:if>
          </div>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483613') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483564')">
          <div class="smalltile" align="center" id="suspense" style="padding-right: 10px;" onmouseover="suspenseHover();" onmouseout="suspenseHoverOut();">
            <br/>

            <label id="suspenselabel" style="position: relative; top: 37px;" class="menuLabelFont">Suspense</label>
            <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483613')">
              <a href="javascript:Submit('../Explorer/ViewTable.aspx?tablepath=suspenseclearing.xml','../Common/','');" title="Manage your suspended transaction" style="cursor: pointer;" class="menuLabelInitiallyHidden" id="commonsuspenseclearanceslabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">Common Suspense Clearances</a>
            <br/>
            <br/>
              </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483564')">
              <a href="javascript:Submit('../Suspense/EditSuspenseTran.aspx','../Common/','');" title="Manage your suspended transaction" style="cursor: pointer;" class="menuLabelInitiallyHidden" id="suspendedtransactionslabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">Suspended Transactions</a>
            </xsl:if>
          </div>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483594')">
          <a href="javascript:Submit('../Transfer/Transfer.aspx','../Common/','');" title="Manage transaction transfers">
            <div class="smalltile" align="center" id="transfer" style="cursor: pointer; padding-top: 57px; padding-right: 10px;" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseleave="unHighlightOrange(this);">
              <img class="images" id="transfericon" 
              <span id ="transferlabel" class="menuLabelFont">Transfer</span>
            </div>
          </a>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483642') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483640') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483536') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483499') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483511') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483577') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483576') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483630') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483627') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483586') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483617') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483584') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483605') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483608') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483606') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483500') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483498')">
          <center>
            <div class="smalltile" align="center" id="admin" style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: 10px;" onmouseover="adminHover();" onmouseleave="outOfAdmin(); adminHoverOut();">
              <br/>
              <img class="imageswithsub" id="adminicon" 
              <label id="adminlabel" style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 4px;" class="adminFont">Admin</label>

              <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483642') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483640')">
                <div class="smalladmintile" align="center" id="admin1" style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: 10px; display: none;">
                  <br/>
                  <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483642')">
                    <a href="javascript:Submit('../Explorer/ViewTable.aspx?tablepath=bankaccounts.xml','../Common/','');" title="Bank Account Configuration" style="cursor: pointer;" class="adminlabel" id="bankaccountslabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">Bank Accounts</a>
                    <br/>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483640')">
                    <a href="javascript:Submit('../Explorer/ViewTable.aspx?tablepath=bankitems.xml','../Common/','');" title="Bank Item Configuration" style="cursor: pointer;" class="adminlabel" id="bankitemconfigurationlabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">Bank Item Configuration</a>
                    <br/>
                  </xsl:if>
                </div>
              </xsl:if>

              <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483536') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483499')">
                <div class="smalladmintile" align="center" id="admin2" style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: 10px; display: none;">
                  <br/>
                  <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483536')">
                    <a href="javascript:Submit('../ParisConfiguration/Bureau.aspx','../Common/','');" title="Bureau" style="cursor: pointer; width: 250px;" class="adminlabel" id="bureaulabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">Bureau</a>
                    <br/>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483499')">
                    <a href="javascript:Submit('../Explorer/ViewTable.aspx?tablepath=bureaupaymentcard.xml','../Common/','');" title="Bureau Payment Card Configuration" style="cursor: pointer;" class="adminlabel" id="bureaupaymentcardlabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">Bureau Payment Card</a>
                    <br/>
                  </xsl:if>
                </div>
              </xsl:if>

              <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483498') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483511')">
                <div class="smalladmintile" align="center" id="admin3" style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: 10px; display: none;">
                  <br/>
                  <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483498')">
                    <a href="javascript:Submit('../Explorer/ViewTable.aspx?tablepath=CCPTemplates.xml','../Common/','');" title="CCPTemplate Configuration" style="cursor: pointer;" class="adminlabel" id="ccptemplateslabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">CCP Templates</a>
                    <br/>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483511')">
                    <a href="javascript:Submit('../ParisConfiguration/PayPal.aspx','../Common/','');" title="PayPal" style="cursor: pointer;" class="adminlabel" id="paypallabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">PayPal</a>
                    <br/>
                  </xsl:if>

                </div>
              </xsl:if>

              <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483577') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483576')">
                <div class="smalladmintile" align="center" id="admin4" style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: 10px; display: none;">
                  <br/>
                  <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483577')">
                    <a href="javascript:Submit('../Explorer/ViewTable.aspx?tablepath=depositmethods.xml','../Common/','');" title="Deposit Methods Configuration" style="cursor: pointer;" class="adminlabel" id="depositmethodslabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">Deposit Methods</a>
                    <br/>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483576')">
                    <a href="javascript:Submit('../Explorer/ViewTable.aspx?tablepath=financialperiod.xml','../Common/','');" title="Financial Periods Configuration" style="cursor: pointer;" class="adminlabel" id="financialperiodslabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">Financial Periods</a>
                    <br/>
                  </xsl:if>
                </div>
              </xsl:if>

              <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483630') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483584') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483627')">
                <div class="smalladmintile" align="center" id="admin5" style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: 10px; display: none;">
                  <br/>
                  <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483584')">
                    <a href="javascript:Submit('../Explorer/ViewTable.aspx?tablepath=returnform.xml','../Common/','');" title="Return Form" style="cursor: pointer;" class="adminlabel" id="returnformlabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">Return Form</a>
                    <br/>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483630')">
                    <a href="javascript:Submit('../Explorer/ViewTable.aspx?tablepath=grouping.xml','../Common/','');" title="Grouping Configuration" style="cursor: pointer;" class="adminlabel" id="groupinglabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">Grouping</a>
                    <br/>
                  </xsl:if>

                  <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483627')">
                    <a href="javascript:Submit('../Explorer/ViewTable.aspx?tablepath=location.xml','../Common/','');" title="Locations Configuration" style="cursor: pointer;" class="adminlabel" id="locationslabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">Locations</a>
                    <br/>
                  </xsl:if>
                </div>
              </xsl:if>

              <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483586')">
                <div class="smalladmintile" align="center" id="admin6" style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: 10px; display: none;">
                  <br/>
                  <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483586')">
                    <a href="javascript:Submit('../Explorer/ViewTable.aspx?tablepath=miscellaneouscode.xml','../Common/','');" title="Miscellaneous Configuration" style="cursor: pointer;" class="adminlabel" id="miscconfiglabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">Miscellaneous Configuration</a>
                    <br/>
                  </xsl:if>
                </div>
              </xsl:if>

              <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483500')">
                <div class="smalladmintile" align="center" id="admin7" style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: 10px; display: none;">
                  <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483500')">
                    <a href="javascript:Submit('../Explorer/ViewTable.aspx?tablepath=integrator.xml','../Common/','');" title="Integrator Configuration" style="cursor: pointer;" class="adminlabel" id="integratorslabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">Integrators</a>
                    <br/>
                  </xsl:if>
                </div>
              </xsl:if>

              <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483617') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483605') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483608') or contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483606')">
                <div class="smalladmintile" align="center" id="admin8" style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: 10px; display: none;">
                  <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483605')">
                    <a href="javascript:Submit('../Explorer/ViewTable.aspx?tablepath=group.xml','../Common/','');" title="Security Groups" style="cursor: pointer;" class="adminlabel" id="securitygroupslabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">Security Groups</a>
                    <br/>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483608')">
                    <a href="javascript:Submit('../Explorer/ViewTable.aspx?tablepath=user.xml','../Common/','');" title="User Management Configuration" style="cursor: pointer;" class="adminlabel" id="usermanagementlabel"  onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">User Management</a>
                    <br/>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483617')">
                    <a href="javascript:Submit('../Explorer/ViewTable.aspx?tablepath=restrictedtask.xml','../Common/','');" title="Restricted Task" style="cursor: pointer;" class="adminlabel" id="restrictedtasklabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">Restricted Task</a>
                    <br/>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="contains($allowedPermissions, '2147483606')">
                    <a href="javascript:Submit('../Explorer/ViewTable.aspx?tablepath=workstations.xml','../Common/','');" title="Workstations Configuration" style="cursor: pointer;" class="adminlabel" id="workstationslabel" onmouseover="highlightOrange(this);" onmouseout="unHighlightOrange(this);">Workstations</a>
                    <br/>
                  </xsl:if>
                </div>
              </xsl:if>

            </div>
          </center>
        </xsl:if>

      </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
  </asp:Table>
</center>
```

I have some images within these divs but have removed these.

CSS:

```
  .smalltile
{
    height: 20%;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #493084;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
    z-index: -1;
    /*position: relative;*/
}

.smalladmintile
{
    height: 25%;
    width: 32%;
    background-color: #493084;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
    z-index: -1;
}

.largetile
{
    height: 60%;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #493084;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    float: left;
    top: auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.adminlabel
{
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,"serif";
    font-size: 18px;
    display: none;
    color: white;
}

.menuLabelFont
{
    color: white;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-family : Verdana,Arial,"serif";
    font-size: 18px;
}

.adminFont
{
    color: white;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 93px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-family : Verdana,Arial,"serif";
    font-size: 18px;
}

.menuLabelInitiallyHidden
{
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,"serif";
    font-size: 18px;
    display: none;
}
```

Within my Javascript function I have the following line of code to change the css class of the admin tile:

```
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('admin').className = 'largetile'; }, menuDelayTimeout);
```

How would I go about getting this large tile to overlap the other div tiles on the page and not display underneath?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Mike

Comment: You have quite a lot of code there, Mike. It would be easier for us to debug if you made a live sample of the issues you're having.

Comment: Agreed. I wanted to use his code but did not want to recreate it.

Comment: Here is the fiddle I have been working on:

https://jsfiddle.net/latherrarge/9v7de9cb/3/

Although I havent been able to get the fiddle fully working as yet, the Javascript function are failing to fire, when hovering over the Admin tile. When you do hover over this tile what I want to happen is the css class of the admin tile gets changed to the large tile class, which should overlap all other tiles not affecting the layout of any of the tiles.

Comment: I have updated the above fiddle. As I couldn't get the Javascript function to fire, I created a new css class for the admin tile, and a new larger tile class for the hover over admin tile. 
At the moment the admin tile gets larger but does not overlap the other div tiles. This is what I wish to achieve. I cannot do this using absolute positioning, as when a user views the page and has different resolutions, the tile displays in different places is positioned using absolute positioning.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/latherrarge/9v7de9cb/10/

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. One of my favorites is based on % to keep things nice and responsive.

I use 3 divs. One container and 2 that overlap one another to create a stack/overlay.

You can use as many layers as you like. This is just a simple sample that you can look at and hopefully apply it in many situations. Content does not matter.

```css
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#photo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#movie {
position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 90%;
    height: 75%;
    top: 6.75%;
    left: 4.25%;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="photo">
    <img src="http://truespeed.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/tvscreen.png" width="100%" height="auto">
    <div id="movie">
       <iframe class="Youtube" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6ydYvG52K-E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/edn2ua31/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

HTML

```
<div class="tile"><div class="tile-contents"></div></div>
<div class="tile big-tile"><div class="tile-contents">Look how I overlap the others :)</div></div>
<div class="tile"><div class="tile-contents"></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.tile {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  float:left;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: steelblue;
}

.tile-contents {
  display:none;
}

.big-tile:hover >.tile-contents {
  display:inline;
  position:absolute;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background:red;
  border:1px solid #fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6K7t4/35/

Answer (score -1):

add this to your largetile CSS

```
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```